# Using sed to insert text at the beginning of each line

Tags: linux, unix, shell, sed, awk

How would one go about using sed in order to insert

```
rm -rf
```

at the start of each line of a file?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
sed 's/^/rm -rf /' filename
```

**EDIT**

Xargs would be simpler way to delete all of the files listed in another file

```
xargs -a filename rm -rf
```

Comment: @Dennis Williamson, nice tip, I pretty much only ever call xargs, when I'm piping in output from another program, so I would never have bothered figuring that out.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
    #if you want to add only to each line matching string
    sed 's/\(^matchingstring.*$\)/"yourtext" \1/' myfile.txt
    
   #if you want to add to each line
    sed 's/^/"yourtext"/' myfile.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to go with the original method using sed, especially when you want to do things like

```
csf -d ipaddr.
```

`xargs` doesn't seem to like the output created by some commands and gives up after the first line. ie:

```
sed 's/^/csf -d /' hacks >>hacks.sh
```